# Dynamically Inserted DOM Elements are not Clickable using $.click()

Tags: jquery, html, css, dynamic

I'm using jQuery to take the value of a form element and place it inside a list item tag. There is a maximum value of three list items (these are to become tags for an image).

The problem is that i want people to be able to remove any erroneous tags they've entered by clicking on them, but the items (which are dynamically inserted into a <ul> tag using jQuery) are not clickable using:

```
$('li.tag').click(function(){ /* Do stuff here */ });
```

it won't even fire off an alert.

Does anyone have any ideas how i can work around this problem?

Comment: When are you calling .click()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for the live method:
http://api.jquery.com/live/

Perhaps you could do something like

```
$('li.tag').live('click', function() { /* Do stuff here */ });
```

Comment: And `.on()` on jQuery >= 1.9

Answer (score 1):

Use [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or `liveQuery` plugin.

Answer (score 0):

As @vmassuchetto mentions, since jQuery 1.7 .live() has been deprecated & removed completely in 1.9. Now you should use .on(). Like so:

```
$('li').on('click', '.tag', function() {
    ...
});
```

> http://api.jquery.com/on/
>
> "Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers."