# Dynamically writing out li with jquery. Element is not clickable after being written

Tags: jquery, dynamic, checkbox, click, html-lists

I have have a a function that when a checkbox is checked i dynamically write out an li into a ol that is empty.

Code:

```
$(":checkbox").click(function() {
    var checkedState = $(this).is(':checked');
    if (checkedState == true) {
       var productName = $(this).attr("title");
       $("#selectedProductsList").append("<li class=\"productList " + this + "\"><p class=\"removeIcon\"><img src=\"images/remove-icon.png\" alt=\"Remove Product\" /></p><span class=\"productName\">"+ productName +"</span></li>");
    };
});
```

Then when that writes out there is a remove icon that will remove the item from the ol when clicked. This remove icon has a class of removeIcon which can be seen in the dynamic li above.

I have a function that processes the remove call and then does some actions:
Code:

```
$('.removeIcon').click(function() {
 alert("starting");
});
```

Right now i have the remove action just trying to alert a message that it got called. But it seems that it is not getting into the function.

Is there a certain way that i need to access these dynamic li's other then the .click method? I saw this post:
[Dynamically Inserted DOM Elements are not Clickable using $.click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412691/dynamically-inserted-dom-elements-are-not-clickable-using-click)

Where they added .live vs .click but this doesn't seem to work either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using the live event...

```
$(".removeIcon").live("click", function () {
    alert("starting");
}
```

Comment: This worked, i didnt have the 'click' part of the live function.

Comment: @estern Excellent, this is my preferred method of handling this issue

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `live()` for dynamically added elements (`$(":checkbox").live('click', ...)`), because `click()` will only run once and will only catch elements that exist up to this point.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead of `live()`.

```
$('#selectedProductsList').delegate('.removeIcon','click',function() {
   alert("starting");
});
```

It would be extremely wasteful to use `.live()` since it appears that the elements you're targeting are all in the same container.

Comment: @estern: Absolutely. They are nearly identical in that they both use "event delegation", which means that the event handler is placed on a container, and that handler processes events that bubble up to that container. But with `.delegate()`, it only needs to process clicks in the `#selectedProductsList`, but with `.live()` it needs to process clicks *in the entire page*. The `live()` method is very popular, and in my opinion, is one of the most unfortunate parts of the API since it isn't really descriptive of what is actually happening. In my opinion, *never ever* use `.live()`.

Comment: WOW thanks for all this great info. Appreciate the time you took to explain these for me.

Answer (score 0):

If got a idea, why dont u put you button in a object? here a little example(NOT TESTED its for helping you on a idea, but should work)

```
$(":checkbox").click(function() {
    var checkedState = $(this).is(':checked');
    if (checkedState == true) {
       var productName = $(this).attr("title");
       var product = $('<li class="productList"><span class="productName">'+ productName +'</span></li>"'); // create a object off the product
       var removeButton = $('<p class="removeIcon"><img src="images/remove-icon.png" alt="Remove Product" /></p>'); // create a object off the image aswell
       // now i can add a event to the object 'removeButton', in the same way what u did earlier(like $('.removeIcon'))
       removeButton.bind('click', function() {
            alert("This click function works");
       });

       // now add the remove button in front off the <span class="productName">
       // im using prepend because that function adds HTML in front off the object
       // append adds HTML at the end.

       product.prepend(removeButton);


       // put the product in your HTML
       $("#selectedProductsList").append(product);
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea i think that i will keep the same method of the image with class for now but this sounds like it could work too.

Comment: @estern, thanks.. in this way you can put all your code in the :checked click function so its organized aswel. and the problem with $('.removeIcon').click(function.... is that when you set this every removeIcon click gets been overwriten/reset(because its already exists in the HTML), and is that what you want? but if another works fine for u, should do it:) goodluck